# WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information error in Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
@Test
    public static void test()

        {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\abcd\\Jars\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        }

    }
```

When i try to execute the above code, webdriver throws the following error. What does the below error mean and how to resolve the issue ?

```
FAILED: test
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: version info not a dictionary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=0.8,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.35 seconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
```

Comment: Does `D:\\abcd\\Jars\\chromedriver.exe` exist? can you open it? Can you run Chrome normally? What version is Chrome?

Comment: @Arran : yes i am able to open and run it manually

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? I would also advise you use the actual ChromeDriver release, not the ChromeDriver2 release - it's experimental and barely works.   https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: @Arran : Thank you. The Driverchange made it work. :)

Comment: Great! Have added it as an answer, if you would accept it that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is due to you using the wrong ChromeDriver release.

ChromeDriver2 is new and improved, rewritten from the ground up and looks promising. However, it is still early days, it is still very broken (breaking some of the tests on Selenium's CI server).

So I'd advise you get the latest **main** release from here and retry:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Try using below format instead of the above one and check if you are still facing the same issue.

```
    File file = new File("D:/abcd/Jars/chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: try using different version of chrome driver.

Comment: Am using chromedriver2_win32_0.8 and this is the only one i can find in the download site(Below one). "http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list.

Comment: i forgot to mention. Try changing the browser version.

Comment: @ HemChe : The driver change made it work. Used Chromedriver instead of Chromedriver2 version as per Arran. Thanks HemChe for ur support